# Issues with getting a scanner in java to close properly

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote method to read an integer using a java scanner. The method is working properly before closing the scanner, but when I try to close the scanner, the program always crashes during the first scan.

Does anyone know whats wrong with this code?

```
private int SINT()
{
    System.out.println("Integer");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int p = 0;
    try 
    {
        p = scan.nextInt();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
        System.out.println("Not integer");
    }
    scan.close();
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Do you get IllegalStateException? Please paste the stack trace of the error.

Comment: What do you mean by `program always crash during the first scan`?

Comment: On reason might be that it is not able to scan the integer value. Always use scan.hasNextInt() before calling scan.nextInt directly.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at Main.Informacie.Scann(Informacie.java:11)
 at Main.Informacie.Menu(Informacie.java:51)
 at Main.Informacie.Info(Informacie.java:30)
 at Main.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Answer (score 3):

You could always create the Scanner within a try-w/resources block, available in Java 1.7. Since it implements the `AutoClosable` interface you can omit the `scan.close()`.

```
int p = 0;
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in))
{
    p = scan.nextInt();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Not integer");
}
return p;
```

Answer (score 1):

> java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown
>   Source)

Your exception is caused when you attempt to read a token from input when there isn't any

So, While you call [next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) , then you should check if scanner has one.

Like this :

```
if(scan.hasNextInt())
 p =scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: Yes, this too would be wise!